# Mock RequestContext to run a test

Tags: activejdbc, javalite, activeweb

I have a class that uses Active Web - HttpSupport View - in a service class.
I know that is wrong but I cannot change right now.

So, when I am running a test I receive a null pointer at this point:

[image]

Because request `context.getValues()` is null.

How I solve it? Is it possible to mock or anything?

Problems:
RequestContext -> private constructor
I am extending AppController -> HttpSupport

My env uses a `@Guice(modules = TestModule.class)` strategy to bind classes in test context.

Answer (score 0):

The class `RequestContext` is internal to the framework and is not designed to be mocked. Is simply carries a number of objects on a local thread for easy access by other framework classes.
This page explains how to write various tests in ActiveWeb: https://javalite.io/testing

This page explains how to mock services that controllers use:
https://javalite.io/dependency_injection

If you add more context to your question, that is: what exactly do you need, I will  be in a better position to advice further

Additionally, the `RequestContext.getValues()` method is not public. Not even sure how you can compile this.

Comment: Let´s try

I am in a service layer ok ?

Added more context

Comment: I do not follow your comment. Can you reply to a question: "what exactly do you need" ?

Comment: 1) is it possible to mock ? RequestContext or 
2) create a simulator for ? RequestContext
3) or initiate RequestContext.getValues();

Comment: <activeweb.version>2.2</activeweb.version>